# Show duplicates in a table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I show all the objects in a table with

```
@models = Model.all
```

Now I need to show in the table only the duplicated objects, a duplicated object is in this case the object with the same integer in tag column. I don´t want to show the objects with a uniq tag.

```
@duplicated_models = Model.xxxxx(:tag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get duplicated tags:

```
tags = Model.group(:tag).select(:tag).having('count(*) > 1').map(&:tag)
```

Then find all objects with duplicated tags:

```
Model.where(tag: tags)
```